# Copying every nth Rows in excel

Tags: excel, optimization, excel-formula, excel-2003, vba

If I have 30 rows, for example, and I want to copy 1st, 2nd and 3rd, skip five, then copy the next three and then skip five again and copy the next three rows: How can I do this? SO far I only have this formula

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(ROW()-1)*5,0)
```

which only gets me one cell value but I would like the entire row copied into another sheet.

Any help would be great! THanks

Comment: Sorry i did not specify, I am willing to use either VBA or formulas. I am also using excel 2003. This formula was put into sheet 2 and dragged down. It collected every 5th value in the desired column. However I would like entire rows copied over.

Answer (score -1):

```
Here is a hint: 
Row Number Modulus 8 in (1,2,3) identifies the target Row Numbers.


Enter in first column, first row and copy down for each column:
=IF(AND(MOD(ROW(Sheet1!A1),8) > 0,MOD(ROW(Sheet1!A1),8) < 4),Sheet1!A1,"")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still wondering how to copy 3 rows, skip the next Nth number of rows, copy 3 rows, skip the next nth number, etc...

Comment: He hinted at modulus.  Put "=MOD(ROW(A1),8)" into cell A1 of a worksheet and drag down, see what happens.

Answer (score -2):

This will do the trick.  just use the Cells(row#, Col#) for your loops.

```
Sub Copy3Skip5()

Dim iRow As Integer
Dim count As Integer
Dim tRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim source As String
Dim target As String

source = "Sheet1"
target = "Sheet2"
'Get the last row on your source sheet.
lastRow = Sheets(source).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
'Set the Target Sheet first row
tRow = 2
'assuming your data starts on Row 2 after a header row.
'Loop through the Source sheet
For iRow = 2 To lastRow
    count = 1
    Do While count <= 3
        'Cells(tRow, 1) translates to Range("A2") if tRow = 2  and "A3" if tRow = 3. and so on
        Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, 1) = Sheets(source).Cells(iRow, 1)
        tRow = tRow + 1
        iRow = iRow + 1
        count = count + 1
    Loop
'add 4 to the iRow, because we already added 1 at the end of the previous loop
    iRow = iRow + 4
Next iRow

End Sub
```

[image: Sheet1]
[image: Result]